# How to Declare a typed Dictionary of Dictionaries in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a `Swift.Dictionary` structure like

```
let tests:[ [String:Any] ] = [
            [ "f" : test1, "on" : true ],
            [ "f" : test2, "on" : false ],
            [ "f" : test3, "on" : false ],
            [ "f" : test4, "on" : false ],
            [ "f" : test5, "on" : false ]
        ]
```

where `f` is a `closure` of type `()->()` and `on` is a `Bool`. I'm using this to enumerate and `eval` the closure based on the `on` value:

```
for (_, test) in tests.enumerate() {
        if test["on"] as! Bool {
            let f:()->()=test["f"] as! ()->();
            f();
        }
    }
```

How to explicitly declare this `Swift.Dictionary` structure in order to avoid to unwrap and to force convert with `as!`:

```
let f:()->()=test["f"] as! ()->();
```

Comment: Use a tuple instead.

Comment: Or even a lightweight struct (that is what I do in an exactly similar situation in one of my apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work? Also it looks a lot cleaner.

```
typealias MyClosure = (() -> ())
typealias MyTuple = (f: MyClosure, on: Bool)

let tests: [MyTuple] = [ etc...

for item in tests {
    if item.on {
        let f = item.f
        f()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes +1 that is what I was searching for!

Comment: @loretoparisi No Problem

Comment: But all he did was exactly what I said, the tuple.

Comment: @matt So? I didn't copy you or anything, I just gave the example

Comment: I'm not complaining to you but to the OP.

Comment: @matt If the OP found my answer more useful because it showed him exactly how to do it with an example then it's understandable he would mark mine as the best answer

Comment: I might have added an example. But the OP argued with me instead of thinking about what I said. You're right I didn't spoon feed him.

Comment: @matt True. It doesn't really matter though now, the OP has an answer. Your answer was better, I guess the OP just likes examples?

Comment: @GabrielJones It was not my intention to cross swords with you here or elsewhere. Let's stay on the same side! All for one and one for all, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very inappropriate use of a dictionary. Make an array of tuples, or even an array of a lightweight struct devised for just this purpose, i.e. to carry a closure-Bool pair.

Comment: ok, but in terms of language, is it possibile to declare `[String:()->()]` and a array of `[[String:()->()]]`, but, please answer the question: is possibile to explicitly declare a type like `[ String : ()->(), String : Bool ]` ?

Comment: You don't need to. The tuple or struct carries the pair of values.